# Is it O(n^2) or O(1)?

Tags: algorithm

> [Is the execution time of this unique string function reduced from the naive O(n^2) approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362644/is-the-execution-time-of-this-unique-string-function-reduced-from-the-naive-on)

This question has a lot of interesting discussion leads me to wonder if we put some threshold on the algorithm, would it change the Big-O running time complexity? For example:

```
void someAlgorithm(n) {
    if (n < SOME_THRESHOLD) {
         // do O(n^2) algorithm
    }
}
```

Would it be O(n<sup>2</sup>) or would it be O(1).

Comment: Is there an `else` condition to your code snippet?  If you don't execute anything above a hard-coded finite value, then the running time will be bounded by a constant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This would be `O(1)`, because there's a constant, such that no matter how big the input is, your algorithm will finish under a time that is smaller than that constant.

Technically, it is also `O(n^2)`, because there's a constant `c` such that no matter how big your input is, your algorithm will finish under `c * n ^ 2` time units. Since big-O gives you the upper bound, everything that is `O(1)` is also `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

If `SOME_THRESHOLD` is constant, then you've hard coded a constant upper bound on the growth of the function (and `f(x) = O (g(x))` gives an upper bound of `g(x)` on the growth of `f(x)`).

By convention, `O(k)` for some constant `k` is just `O(1)` because we don't care about constant factors.

Note that the lower bound is unknown, a least theoretically, because we don't know anything about the lower bound of the `O(n^2)` function. We know that for `f(x) = Omega(h(x))`, `h(x) <= 1` because `f(x) = O(1)`. Less than constant-time functions are possible [in theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms), although in practice `h(x) = 1`, so `f(x) = Omega(1)`.

What all this means is by forcing a constant upper bound on the function, the function now has a tight bound: `f(x) = Theta(1)`.

Comment: Depending on the computational model, you might actually have f(n) = Theta(0)